# Is the Microsoft Surface Book capable for running Mechanical Engineering apps efficiently?

Tags: laptop

May I know whether Microsoft Surface Book capable for running Mechanical Engineering apps efficiently?

I am using software such as MATLAB with simulink, STK, AutoCAD, solidworks, and ANSYS workbench.

I am a research student and my next laptop should be travel supportive, and fir within a budget of 500 Euros.

Microsoft Surface Book, i5, 6th generation 128 SSD, 8 GB RAM are the specs of this laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will run these programs. How well depends on your expectations. It's a dual-core CPU with relatively low clock speeds. At least the RAM is configured in dual-channel mode, but it's only 8GB, and can not be upgraded. Same with the tiny SSD. While that could technically be upgraded, it is not straightforward at all. Ifixit gave it a 1 out of 10 for repairability https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Microsoft+Surface+Book+Teardown/51972

If I had 500$ with your requirements, I would get something like a Thinkpad T460p with a quad-core CPU. While it may not look as sexy as a surface book, it can easily be upgraded and serviced. The latter is a rather important trait for used laptops. And it beats the Surface Book in the performance department.

Comment: Lenovo's hardware manuals are superb, and they are hands down the easiest machines to work on and upgrade.

Comment: @MechEng May I know any Dell laptops that can meet the requirements?

Comment: I am not aware of any Dell laptop with similar specs as a T460p, at that price point. Dells "Precision" mobile workstations don't come in a 14" form factor, and the lower end "Latitude" series at the 500$ mark have dual core CPUs. But maybe someone who is more familiar with Dell laptops has a better idea.